# ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND bundle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

I'm starting to use webpack, and I did a tiny project to try, but I'm finding an error that I don't know how to fix. When I run my index.html, it says that can't find bundle.js. I think is something wrong with the path, but I'm not sure. Hope someone can help me!

**This is my structure**

```
prueba1
    node_modules
    build
        bundle.js
    src
        app.js
        index.html
        messages.js
        style.css
    package.lock.json
    package.json
    webpack.config.js
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="connect">Conectar</button>

        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "prueba1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.51.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/build",
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `index.html` and your `bundle.js` are in different directories (`src` and `build`). You could simply move your `index.html` to `build` and it will work.

Or you let webpack do that work with the `copy-webpack-plugin` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin): install it using `npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev`, and add this to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "src", to: "build" }
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!